# Como filtrar en un Datatable con un select BETWEEN con dos campos de fechas type date

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Saludos soy nuevo en mvc espero me ayuden... tengo una tabla ventas y quiero filtrar la información por dos campos fecha para generar un reporte. es un datatable, asi no me funciona los datos filtrados no son correctos quiero filtrarlos con linq o de esta manera ayudaa por favor.

**vista**

```
     <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">SELECCIONE FECHAS:</h5>
                    <form class="form-inline float-md-left">
                        <label for="profilePhone" style=" font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;  font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;  font-size: 16px; color:#DC4503">FECHA INICIO:   &emsp;</label>
                        <div></div>
                        <div><input name="min" id="min"  type="date"  style=" font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;  font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;  font-size: 16px; color:black"></div>
                        <div>
                            &emsp;
                        </div>

                        <label for="profilePhone" style=" font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;  font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;  font-size: 16px; color:#DC4503">FECHA FIN:   &emsp;</label>
                        <div><input name="max" id="max" type="date"  style=" font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;  font-weight: bold; text-transform: uppercase;  font-size: 16px; color:black"></div>

                    </form>

                    <div class="table-responsive mt-40">


                        <div id="myTable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">


                            <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr role="row" style="color:black">
                                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="myTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 60px; font-weight: bold; ">ID#</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="myTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 140px; font-weight: bold;">FECHA FACTURA</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="myTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 140px; font-weight: bold;">CLIENTE</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="myTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 140px; font-weight: bold;">MÉTODO DE PAGO</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="myTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column ascending" aria-sort="ascending" style="width: 90px; font-weight: bold;">RECIBIDO</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="myTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 90px; font-weight: bold;">CAMBIO</th>
                                        <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="myTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ID: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 90px; font-weight: bold;">TOTAL</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                    @foreach (var invoice in Model.Invoices)
                                    {
                                        <tr role="row" class="odd">

                                            <td style="color:black">
                                                @invoice.InvoiceID

                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @invoice.DateInvoice
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @if (invoice.Customer != null)
                                                {
                                                    <text>@invoice.Customer.FullName</text>
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    <text>-</text>
                                                }
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @if (invoice.PaymentMethod != null)
                                                {
                                                    <text>@invoice.PaymentMethod.Name</text>
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    <text>-</text>
                                                }
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @invoice.Receipt
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @invoice.PayBack
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @invoice.TotalSale

                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

este es el Script que uso, lo tome de un ejemplo pero no funciona bien y llevo 3 dias atascado con este problema, ya que no he encontrado muchos ejemplos en internet

```
   <script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            var min = $('#min').datepicker("getDate");
            var max = $('#max').datepicker("getDate");
            var startDate = new Date(data[4]);
            if (min == null && max == null) { return true; }
            if (min == null && startDate <= max) { return true; }
            if (max == null && startDate >= min) { return true; }
            if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) { return true; }
            return false;
        }
    );


    $("#min").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    $("#max").datepicker({ onSelect: function () { table.draw(); }, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

    // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
    $('#min, #max').change(function () {
        table.draw();
    });
});</script>
```

COntrolador este es en controlador que uso para mandar los datos de las ventas a la vista

```
 public ActionResult ReportPOS()
    {
        List<Invoice> Invoices = db.Invoices.ToList();

        InvoiceData Data = new InvoiceData();
        Data.User = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        Data.Invoices = Invoices;

        return View(Data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo

```js
$(function() {
  var oTable = $('#datatable').DataTable();

  $("#fechaDesde").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    "onSelect": function(date) {
      minimo = new Date(date).getTime();
      oTable.fnDraw();
    }
  }).keyup(function() {
    minimo = new Date(this.value).getTime();
    oTable.fnDraw();
  });

  $("#fechaHasta").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    "onSelect": function(date) {
      maximo = new Date(date).getTime();
      oTable.fnDraw();
    }
  }).keyup(function() {
    maximo = new Date(this.value).getTime();
    oTable.fnDraw();
  });

});

// Date range filter
minimo = "";
maximo = "";

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if (typeof aData._date == 'undefined') {
      aData._date = new Date(aData[0]).getTime();
    }

    if (minimo && !isNaN(minimo)) {
      if (aData._date < minimo) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    if (maximo && !isNaN(maximo)) {
      if (aData._date > maximo) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>
    <span>Desde: </span><input id="fechaDesde" />
    <span>Hasta:<input id="fechaHasta" />
  </p>
  <table width="100%" id="datatable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          04/05/2020
        </td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          04/06/2020
        </td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          04/07/2020
        </td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          04/20/2020
        </td>
        <td>17</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          04/21/2020
        </td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: saludos, gracias por ayudarme pero me sale un error, ReportPOS:386 Uncaught TypeError: oTable.fnDraw is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onSelect (ReportPOS:386)
    at Datepicker._selectDate (jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:8215)
    at Datepicker._selectDay (jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:8191)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.selectDay (jquery-ui-1.12.1.js:8789)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.dispatch (VM1542 jquery-3.4.1.js:5237)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.elemData.handle (VM1542 jquery-3.4.1.js:5044)

Comment: si pudieras ayudarme te lo agradeceria bastante

Comment: Pienso que pueden ser las versions de las librerias, por ejemplo en tu error se muestra jquery-ui-1.12.1.js en mi caso  uso 1.10 talvez puedas revisar todas las versiones